# Hyperledger fabric make error when it makes couchdb docker part?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

everyone . I have a problem here. when i do the process follow the  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/build.html.  With "make dist-clean all", when it runs to make couchdb docker, there are some error occur. "writing more data than expected". how can i sovle this?

Here is the terminal msg:

```
    The following additional packages will be installed:
  cmake-data erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-corba erlang-crypto
  erlang-diameter erlang-edoc erlang-eldap erlang-erl-docgen erlang-eunit
  erlang-ic erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-odbc erlang-os-mon
  erlang-parsetools erlang-percept erlang-public-key erlang-runtime-tools
  erlang-snmp erlang-ssh erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tools
  erlang-webtool erlang-wx erlang-xmerl icu-devtools libarchive13 libcurl3
  libcurl3-gnutls libffi-dev libglu1-mesa libjsoncpp1 liblua5.3-0 liblzo2-2
  libnotify4 libnspr4-dev libodbc1 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-0v5
Suggested packages:
  codeblocks eclipse ninja-build erlang erlang-manpages erlang-doc xsltproc
  fop erlang-ic-java erlang-observer vim-haproxy haproxy-doc lrzip
  libcurl4-doc libcurl3-dbg libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev
  libssl-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev icu-doc libmyodbc odbc-postgresql tdsodbc
  unixodbc-bin
Recommended packages:
  libsctp1 notification-daemon
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https cmake cmake-data erlang-asn1 erlang-base erlang-corba
  erlang-crypto erlang-dev erlang-diameter erlang-edoc erlang-eldap
  erlang-erl-docgen erlang-eunit erlang-ic erlang-inets erlang-mnesia
  erlang-nox erlang-odbc erlang-os-mon erlang-parsetools erlang-percept
  erlang-public-key erlang-reltool erlang-runtime-tools erlang-snmp erlang-ssh
  erlang-ssl erlang-syntax-tools erlang-tools erlang-webtool erlang-wx
  erlang-xmerl haproxy icu-devtools libarchive13 libcurl3 libcurl4-openssl-dev
  libffi-dev libglu1-mesa libicu-dev libicu55-dbg libjsoncpp1 liblua5.3-0
  liblzo2-2 libmozjs185-1.0 libmozjs185-dev libnotify4 libnspr4-dev libodbc1
  libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-0v5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ca-certificates curl libcurl3-gnutls libicu55
4 upgraded, 51 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.
Need to get 60.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 157 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 cmake-data all
3.5.1-1ubuntu3 [1121 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liblzo2-2 amd64 2.08-1.
2 [48.7 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libarchive13 am
d64 3.1.2-11ubuntu0.16.04.3 [262 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libcurl3 amd64
7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4 [186 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libjsoncpp1 amd64 1.7.2
-1 [73.0 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 cmake amd64 3.5
.1-1ubuntu3 [2623 kB]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 cmake amd64 3.5
.1-1ubuntu3
  Writing more data than expected (7722428 > 7658434)
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libnotify4 amd64 0.7.6-
2svn1 [17.2 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.47
.0-1ubuntu2.4 [139 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libcurl3-gnutls
 amd64 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4 [184 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apt-transport-
https amd64 1.2.24 [26.1 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ca-certificate
s all 20170717~16.04.1 [168 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libicu55 amd64
 55.1-7ubuntu0.3 [7658 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-base amd64 1:18
.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [6962 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-asn1 amd64 1:18
.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [709 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-mnesia amd64 1:
18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [664 kB]
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-runtime-tools a
md64 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3
  502  cannotconnect
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-crypto amd64 1:
18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [106 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-public-key amd6
4 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [524 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-ssl amd64 1:18.
3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [658 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-inets amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [714 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-corba amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [2233 kB]
Err:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-corba amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3
  Writing more data than expected (2236127 > 2232914)
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-dev amd64 1:18.
3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [332 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-syntax-tools am
d64 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [322 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-diameter amd64
1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [643 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-xmerl amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [956 kB]
Err:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-xmerl amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3
  Writing more data than expected (1530735 > 1527518)
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-edoc amd64 1:18
.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [293 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-eldap amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [99.1 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-erl-docgen amd6
4 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [132 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-eunit amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [135 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-ic amd64 1:18.3
-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [816 kB]
Err:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-ic amd64 1:18.3
-dfsg-1ubuntu3
  Writing more data than expected (1579306 > 1527518)
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libodbc1 amd64 2.3.1-4
.1 [180 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-odbc amd64 1:18
.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [47.2 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-snmp amd64 1:18
.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [1528 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-os-mon amd64 1:
18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [89.6 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-parsetools amd6
4 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [153 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-percept amd64 1
:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [132 kB]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-ssh amd64 1:18.
3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [430 kB]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-webtool amd64 1
:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [35.6 kB]
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-tools amd64 1:1
8.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [517 kB]
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 erlang-nox all 1:18.3-
dfsg-1ubuntu3 [14.0 kB]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libglu1-mesa amd64 9.0
.0-2.1 [168 kB]
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 libwxbase3
.0-0v5 amd64 3.0.2+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.1 [971 kB]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 libwxgtk3.
0-0v5 amd64 3.0.2+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.1 [4344 kB]
Err:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 libwxgtk3.
0-0v5 amd64 3.0.2+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.1
  Writing more data than expected (8547360 > 8532330)
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 erlang-wx amd64 1:
18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [2764 kB]
Err:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 erlang-wx amd64 1:
18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3
  Writing more data than expected (8535247 > 8532330)
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 erlang-reltool amd
64 1:18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3 [343 kB]
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liblua5.3-0 amd64 5.3.
1-1ubuntu2 [116 kB]
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 haproxy amd64
1.6.3-1ubuntu0.1 [756 kB]
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 icu-devtools a
md64 55.1-7ubuntu0.3 [166 kB]
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libcurl4-opens
sl-dev amd64 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.4 [262 kB]
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libicu-dev amd
64 55.1-7ubuntu0.3 [8532 kB]
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnspr4-dev a
md64 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [213 kB]
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libffi-dev amd64 3.2.1
-4 [161 kB]
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libicu55-dbg a
md64 55.1-7ubuntu0.3 [6755 kB]
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libmozjs185-1.0 am
d64 1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-4.5 [1117 kB]
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libmozjs185-dev am
d64 1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-4.5 [1566 kB]
Fetched 46.4 MB in 7min 44s (100 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cmake/cmake_3.5.
1-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Writing more data than expected (7722428 > 7658434)

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/erlang/erlang-ru
ntime-tools_18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  502  cannotconnect

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/erlang/erlang-co
rba_18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Writing more data than expected (2236127 > 223
2914)

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/erlang/erlang-xm
erl_18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Writing more data than expected (1530735 > 152
7518)

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/erlang/erlang-ic
_18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Writing more data than expected (1579306 > 152751
8)

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets3.0
/libwxgtk3.0-0v5_3.0.2+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  Writing more data than expec
ted (8547360 > 8532330)

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/e/erlang/erlan
g-wx_18.3-dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Writing more data than expected (8535247 > 85
32330)

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mis
sing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-rec
ommends     ca-certificates     curl     erlang-nox     erlang-reltool     hapro
xy     libicu5.     libmozjs185-1.0     openssl     cmake     apt-transport-http
s     gcc     g++     erlang-dev     libcurl4-openssl-dev     libicu-dev     lib
mozjs185-dev     make   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code
: 100
Makefile:285: recipe for target 'build/image/couchdb/.dummy-x86_64-1.1.0-snapsho
t-43d3e63' failed
make: *** [build/image/couchdb/.dummy-x86_64-1.1.0-snapshot-43d3e63] Error 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because my network is behind a proxy, and I change the apt source to the location of my proxy(jp). and do apt-get update again, and apt-get install. That's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the issue is the the Ubuntu mirrors were being updated.  You might want to try again (if you have not already resolved this)

Comment: Glad to hear it